# Install ZoneMinder on Rasp. Zero W

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 4b, which I installed Raspbian and ZoneMinder.

I have 4 Raspberry Pi Zero W with camera, I want to make a surveillance system here at home.

But to add the rasp. Zero to ZoneMinder, I need ...

**rtsp: // username : password @ ipaddress : port / somepath**

Ipaddresseu with you with an app on your phone, I scan my network and find out which ones devices are on my network, so I discover the ip.
But how do I know the username, password, port and somepath?
The rasp. Zero W, it's plugged in, and just give me the ip, where I find these other information? I think I'm forgetting or needing something else, to obtain such data.

Another question, the systems on the Internet that I’ve been looking for besides ZoneMinder,
use either MJPEG-Streamer or MotionEye, so ZoneMinder seems to be just a server that needs another program, is that it?

Last doubt, what is the difference between connecting the cameras in http and rstp in ZoneMinder?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `username, password, ipaddress, port, somepath` would all depend on how you set up an rtsp server on the pi 0W

Comment: That's three questions.  Please ask them separately so they may be answered and voted upn separately.

Comment: Do I need an rtsp server, then? Only the zoneminder installed on a raspberry 4b, wouldn't this be the server?